# JavaScript to click a button after a random number of seconds?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to optimize my JavaScript code to be a short as possible (this is just for fun). Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Basically, the script automatically clicks an "I'm still here" button on a website. To do that, it checks every 100 ms for the prompt (class `.dialog-box`), and if it sees it, it waits between 1 and 5 seconds and then clicks the "I'm here" button (class `.here-button`).

```
function delay(n){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(resolve,n);
    });
}

let p=x => document.querySelector(x);

(async function() {
    while(true){
        await delay(100);
        if(x=p(".dialog-box")) {
            x.style.visibility = "hidden";
            await delay(1e3+4e3*Math.random());
            console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + ": Clicked");
            p(".here-button").click();
        }
    }
})();
```

I'm going to run it through a minifier as well, but I'm curious if there are ways to make the code shorter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you really want it as short as possible, you want [codegolf.se] rather than Code Review.

Comment: Thanks, Toby! I wasn't aware that existed (I was sent here from Stack Overflow)--good to know!

Comment: What is the *performance* angle about the problem at hand?

Comment: @greybeard I wasn't clear in my description, but I'd love to make the code efficient as well--my brute force method of looking for the dialog box ten times a second seems wasteful.

Comment: Requests for minification are out-of-scope for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice using scientific notation to shave a character off those milliseconds.

Instead of using async and promises, you could just run an anonymous interval every 100ms. Each time the interval runs, it checks for the `.dialog-box` element. If it finds it, it stops searching until after it waits for 1–5 seconds and clicks the `.here-button` element—then resumes searching.

**A human-friendly version**

```js
let searching = 1, getElement = selector => document.querySelector(selector)
setInterval(() => {
  if (searching && getElement('.dialog-box')) {
    searching = 0
    setTimeout(() => {
      getElement('.here-button').click()
      searching = 1
    }, 1e3 + 4e3 * Math.random())
  }
}, 100)
```

**Shortened variable names**

```js
let s = 1, e = s => document.querySelector(s)
setInterval(() => {
  if (s && e('.dialog-box')) {
    s = 0
    setTimeout(() => {
      e('.here-button').click()
      s = 1
    }, 1e3 + 4e3 * Math.random())
  }
}, 100)
```

**Minified** (160 characters)

```js
let s=1,e=s=>document.querySelector(s);setInterval(()=>{if(s&&e('.dialog-box')){s=0;setTimeout(()=>{e('.here-button').click();s=1},1e3+4e3*Math.random())}},100)
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! And even if I add back the lines to hide the dialog box and log to console with the time, I'm still dozens characters shaved off!

Comment: I'm not crazy about using numbers as booleans, among other practices here. `searching = 0` should be `searching = false`. That's unacceptable even in C nowadays. If your goal is shortness, then this seems halfway in, halfway out because there are plenty of other ways to shorten things, so I'd suggest going all-readability and let the minifier handle the rest. I also prefer the async/promise approach from the original; it's so nice that it's been [made standard in Node 17](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers-promises-api).

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I didn't realize the promise thing was so widely adopted.

Comment: @ggorlen The question asks to make the code shorter, for fun. Not to make it more performant or readable.

Comment: Yes, that's clearly your/OP's intent, but then why not drop `let`, use `&` instead of `&&`, and `_` instead of `()`? I'm not much of a code golfer but these seem like low-hanging fruit.

Answer (score 3):

What's the benefit of trying to minify or shorten the code *in situ*? As Sean showed, you can always plop it into a minifier, but while coding, shorthand like

```js
let p=x => document.querySelector(x);
```

is probably not too helpful to your future self that might want to maintain or debug the script. Sometimes I see this aliased using the `$` variable (when jQuery isn't otherwise being used:

```js
const $ = x => document.querySelector(x);
const $$ = x => document.querySelectorAll(x);
```

(note I've used `const` instead of the weaker `let`; we don't want to accidentally reassign this variable)

#### Style nitpicks

I'd suggest using an autoformatter like [prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier) or the internal Stack Snippets editor.

- `function delay(n){` -> `function delay(ms) {`
- `setTimeout(resolve,n);` -> `setTimeout(resolve, ms);`
- `while(true){` -> `while (true) {` or `for (;;) {`
- `1000` is much clearer than `1e3` to me -- it's not worth shaving a character.

#### Bigger issues

The line:

```js
if(x=p(".dialog-box")) {
```

creates a global variable `x` attached to the window which can potentially cause a bug. If you put `"use strict";` at the top of your script, you'll get a nice error protecting you from yourself. As a rule of thumb, don't do assignments in conditions like this unless you really know what you're doing and are sure it's going to read more cleanly than moving it to a separate line.

If you're running this as a bookmarklet or userscript on another site, I would put all of the code into the IIFE closure so to avoid clashing with globals.

Secondly, do you need to poll like this, or can you use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)? Observing mutations means you won't need to burn cycles continually to keep checking the predicate; the code will only run when there's a DOM mutation on the watched subtree. Without seeing a representative sample of the page this works on, it's hard to say much more though.

It's probably not applicable here, but [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) will give you a tighter polling loop and is often a useful tool for these userscript situations.

#### A quick rewrite

```js
(async () => {
  "use strict";

  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  const $ = x => document.querySelector(x);

  for (;;) {
    await delay(100);
    const elem = $(".dialog-box");

    if (elem) {
      elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
      await delay(1000 + 4000 * Math.random());
      console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + ": Clicked");
      $(".here-button").click();
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="dialog-box"></div>
<button class="here-button"></button>
```

Comment: Super thorough and thoughtful--thank you! This is just a script I was playing with to get used to JavaScript, and so I was trying to figure out inefficiencies in my code. I'll take a look at `MutationObserver` as well, as I think you're right that that would run better!

Comment: I've never seen an expressionless `for` loop without a `break` statement. Surely a `while` loop would be better for your readability directive if you're critiquing ones and zeroes being used for booleans. Also, the request was to make it shorter, which it doesn't seem like you've done.

Comment: @Sean From what I've seen, the site is primarily about [code review, not code golf](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/711/171065), so it seems OK to review a golfing request with a normal code review. As I mentioned in the other thread, OP only seems to be half-attempting to golf, as does your answer, so I erred on the side of not-golf. From my experience, `for (;;)` is roughly as common an idiom as a `while (true)` for creating infinite loops, but I'd be just fine with `while` if you prefer -- it's not really integral to my response.